# Car AC not equal on driver passenger side

Tags: ac

I've 2010 Hyundai SantaFe with somewhat weak AC. What I noticed is car AC is not equally powerful on passenger and driver side. Passenger side seems to be working much better and it is not dual control AC.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: When was the AC system last serviced? Sounds like low refrigerant to me. Additionally, when was the cabin air filter last replaced if there's one?

Comment: @Al_ I recently bought the car so don't have idea about those things. I will check those things.

Comment: Definitely check them as soon as you can. Also, consider yourself lucky that your AC is working at all on a second hand car. Don't push your luck too much though, have the system tested for leaks and then everything evacuated, vacuumed and then the original refrigerant charge restored and, in the meanwhile, don't turn the AC on. AC Compressors hate low refrigerant. It can make them seize up due to low lubrication.